# Are objects in reactive arrays reactive

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue 3 application that uses a Pinia store to store an array of Javascript objects.

```
// QuestionStore.ts

export interface qn {
    id: string,
    text: string
}

const initStore = {
    qnArray: <qn[]>[]
} 

export const useQuestionStore = defineStore('QuestionStore', () => {
    const displayedQuestions = reactive(structuredClone(initStore))

    // Store getter and setter
    function getDisplayedQuestion(i : Number) { return displayedQuestions.qnArray[i] }
    function setDisplayedQuestion(i : Number, q : qn) {
        displayedQuestions.qnArray[i] = q
    }
})
```

I want to add and modify objects in the store by reference in my application's components.

In the following code, `activeQn` is a local variable in the component:

```
// MyComponent.vue

const activeQn : qn = reactive({...emptyQn})

// Line 1: Set first question in store as active question
activeQn = getDisplayedQuestion(0)

// Line 2: Set active question as second question in store
setDisplayedQuestion(1, activeQn)
```

The objective is to pass `activeQn` by reference into the store, so that any updates to `activeQn` (such as via user input) are also automatically reflected in the store. Do the above two lines of code accomplish this? If not, how should I modify them?

Answer (score 1):

In Vue 3 and Pinia, objects in a reactive array are reactive. But your current code doesn't update the store when you change activeQn because each assignment makes a new reference.

To keep the same reference, don't reassign activeQn. Instead, directly change its properties. For example:

```
// MyComponent.vue
const activeQn = reactive({...getDisplayedQuestion(0)});
activeQn.text = "New text"; // changes will reflect in store
```

And, instead of replacing the question in the store, update its properties:

```
// in QuestionStore.ts
function setDisplayedQuestion(i : Number, q : qn) {
  Object.assign(displayedQuestions.qnArray[i], q);
}
```

With these changes, updates to activeQn should be reflected in the store.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Does this mean that, when I want to change the question being displayed, I can just call `activeQn = reactive({...getDisplayedQuestion(2)})` again? And for the `setDisplayedQuestion` function, do I need to call it everytime I update the `activeQn` variable (from what I understand, `Object.assign` copies over the properties by value)?

Comment: Reassigning activeQn breaks the reactivity link to the store. Instead, update properties directly, e.g., `activeQn.text = "New text"` And to update the store, use `Object.assign(displayedQuestions.qnArray[i], q)` to copy over the properties without breaking reactivity. Call this update function whenever activeQn is changed to reflect updates in the store.